# Perl: how to use local copy of module instead of installed version?

Tags: perl

I'm making changes to an installed Perl module, and I'd like to make those changes in a local copy first before copying them to the installed copy.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get Perl to use the local version over the installed version. I tried pushing the local directory to the beginning and end of `@INC`, hoping that would do it, but it didn't.

The only solution I've found is renaming everything, which I actually started to do, but it involves so many files that I'm just making a mess by going into every file and renaming everything. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You sure you don't want to show us an example of what didn't work?  For example, have you taken in to account that `use` is processed at compile time, while `push` and `unshift` will wait until the execution phase unless put in a `BEGIN`block.

Comment: Yes, they're in a begin block. The problem seems to be that all of the sub modules use the full package name at the top of each file.

Answer (score 2):

```
use lib 'your/local/lib/path';
use MyModule; #this should load ./your/local/lib/path/MyModule.pm
```

Can you post an example of what doesn't work?